# Finding descent direction of quadratic function

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratics, descent

I have a quadratic function:  $f(x) = 24x_1+14x_2+x_1x_2$
and point $x_0 = (2,10)^T$ with $f(x_0) = 208$

And the first question is "give descent direction r in $x_0$"
The second question "is f convex in direction r?

How can I do that? I've already determine gradient and Hessean. But which step should be next?
According to descent ditrection I fount such formula in the Inet:
$r=-\partial{^2}f(x)\partial{f(x)}$ Is that formula correct?

About second question: If Hessean is positive for any x, it means, that f is convex But how to determine whether f convex  $\mathbf{in}$  $\mathbf{direction }$?

Answer (score 3):

(Steepest) descent direction is $-\nabla f(x_0)$. Which is $(-34,-16)^T$ in your case.

To find if $f$ is convex in direction $\vec r$, plug $\vec r$ into the quadratic form associated with the Hessian matrix:  $ \vec r^T H \vec r$  gives the second directional derivative in direction $\vec r$. Positive=convex, negative=concave...  Here 
$$(-34,-16)\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} (-34,-16)^T = 2\cdot 24\cdot 16>0$$ 
Notice that the sign of $\vec r$ does not matter: changing the vector to opposite does not affect convexity in that direction.